FATAL: role "root" does not exist
Подскажите в чём может быть проблема, делаю docker-compose.yml, как обычно, а тут такое: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist. А yoyo-migrations вообще тянет POSTGRES_USER из системы (мой на компе)
version: '3.8'

services:
  users1:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "50051:50051"
    depends_on:
      - migration
  
  users2:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "50052:50051"
    depends_on:
      - migration
  
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    image: postgres:14.11
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", '-q', '-U', "${DB_USER}", "-d", "${DB_NAME}"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  migration:
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    image: python:3.12.3
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    command: sh -c "pip install psycopg2-binary yoyo-migrations && yoyo apply --database postgresql://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@db:5432/${DB_NAME} ./migrations"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
  
volumes:
  db-data:

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12.3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt 

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "src/main.py"]

Помогите пожалуйста, уже час сижу, посмотрел и на StackoverFlow и у ChatGPT

Помогло следующее: source .env & docker compose up
